# git add command fails and keeps running

Tags: git

I run command:

```
git add .
```

and get:

```
Killed: 9
```

It stops me running any git commands with a lock.

What is wrong with my git, I've tried rebooting, removing the directory and starting over with a new repo.

Comment: Please, can you show us the full error log?

Comment: How many files are in that directory?  Might there be locks or other problems with any of the files?

Comment: `Killed: 9` suggests possibly your system is running out of memory. What OS are you using?

Comment: How did you solve this problem?

Comment: It seems you have add too many files to git, you can check if there is some directories under PWD that have the files should not be added to git

Answer (score 39):

I was able to solve the same issue by adding things (that should not be in Git) to `.gitignore`.  In my specific case, there was a nested directory which had a Python virtualenv directory.

After adding `venv/` to my `.gitignore` and committing, I was finally able to commit the directory.

Comment: Same over here, I had to exclude python's virtual env directory to make it not crash.

Comment: That was my issue as well!

Comment: same issue here

Comment: Same issue here.

Answer (score 10):

Same issue here, different solution (iOS project):

I did a `pod update` in my project, but cancelled it with `ctrl+c`. After that all my git commands were failing with

```
Killed: 9
```

I had to re launch my `pod update` and let it finish, then delete the git lock with

```
rm .git/index.lock
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a git from Apple, maybe shifting to non-Apple version will work.

I got similar error like this:

```
$ git add demo
[1]    32003 killed     git add demo
```

I checked my git version and found it came from Apple.

```
$ git --version
git version 2.20.1 (Apple Git-117)
$ which git
/usr/bin/git
```

after installing git from brew, it works.

```
$ /usr/local/bin/git add demo
$ /usr/local/bin/git --version
git version 2.26.2
```

But only this specify file (named 'demo') got `git add` killed.

```
$ file demo
demo: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

This file is about 22M, I tested a 30M zero file (generated by `dd`) and a simple hello-world file generated by `gcc`(file format Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64), they all work.

Maybe shifting to official git will work. I have no idea why Apple-version git does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by triggering a re-install of the command line tools.

To do so, open a terminal and run `xcode-select --install`. You'll get a prompt that will walk you through installing it.

Additionally, I saw that homebrew somehow hijacked my reversion of git.

You can determine that by running `which git`. The result should be `/usr/bin/git`. If it shows homebrew or brew anywhere in the path, you need to run `brew uninstall git`. Open a new tab, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score -2):

no. after new version of github. U need to run pod update before using git