# 'Killed: 9' when using git add *

Tags: git, github

I have an error when using

```
git add *
```

which just says

```
Killed: 9
```

If I type git add * again I get

```
fatal: Unable to create 
'.git/index.lock': File exists.

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.
```

If I remove .git/index.lock and type git add * again, I get the killed error again.

I checked other answers on stackoverflow like

[git add command fails and keeps running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40375637/git-add-command-fails-and-keeps-running)

but I do not use any virtual environment.

Answer (score 4):

In my case (adding Cocoapods dependencies folder to git which can be fairly large), the issue was Apple's git in macOS Catalina. Updating with `brew install git` solved it.

It's necessary to start a new Terminal session for the new version to  become available.

Answer (score 1):

Try instead what the other answer is using: `git add .` instead of `git add` *.

That will avoid the shell to interpret `*` and expand it to all non-dot files.
`git add .` will leave git to determine what needs to be added.

Comment: Same problem "git add . -> Killed: 9"

Answer (score 1):

`killed: 9` means your process (`git add`) was killed via signal number 9, which is `SIGKILL`, which is the signal used by the Out Of Memory (OOM) killer on Linux and similar systems.

The OOM killer activates when the overall system is low on memory.  It finds some victim process(es) to kill and kills them off so that the system-as-a-whole remains up, even if those processes terminate.  The victim processes are not necessarily the cause of the system running out of memory.

The cure is to figure out why the system is running out of memory, and/or add more memory.  In the meantime, you may be able to add some file(s) and not others.  You may be running out of memory because some files are particularly large, e.g., perhaps you have a four terabyte file that you probably should not commit. :-)

Comment: [People say](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42319586/7976758) it happens when one is trying to add a huge directory tree. Python virtualenv, for example.

Comment: As @phd described, this happened to me when adding a virtual environment to the project folders. I added the virtual environment directory to .ignore file and fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error trying to add a directory that I did `sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine Lib/` on.

I needed to do the `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine` dance because there where multiple executables in the library that I needed.

I solved it by instead doing `xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine Lib.zip` on the zip-file in my Downloads folder, then unzip and add to git, this time with no errors.

Hope this saves someone some time.